# Getting Stack Overflow like Title field on other Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, user-interface

When editing my network profile, [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) gives me the ability to set a Title field which gets displayed just below my name when someone views my profile page.

[image] [image]

However, the same is not available on other Stack Exchange sites.

[image] [image]

I tried by clicking the **Save and copy changes to all public communities** button when editing my profile on Stack Overflow but that didn't make the title appear on other sites.

Is there a way to get the title field added to other network sites? Is this something that can be configured by site mods?

How can I go about requesting this feature?

Comment: Good catch., ON SO there is an `<h3>` tag with the title. On other sites that tag is not even rendered so I assume it is intentional lef out. It could be related/linked to Jobs/careers which is only available on SO proper. There was a bug on that field last week: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385813/dont-show-old-title-when-a-user-removes-it-from-the-profile

Comment: @rene I get that the field is intentional made unavailable. However, I'd like the ability of having it on other network sites too. Just voicing the desired.

Comment: Just voicing extra background information to support your FR ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Overflow has had an extended profile feature for some time, first the [CV](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312452/4751173) for [Stack Overflow Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs) and then the [Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313960/4751173). The title field is [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381158/4751173) to them; [how exactly is a mystery](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/377872/4751173). But that's probably the reason the field is only available on Stack Overflow and not on the other sites in the network (and IMHO it's likely to stay that way).

As an alternative, use the first line of your 'About me' to display your job title. Many people do so already (though I can't find an example right now). The text will not be in gray but that will even improve readability.